# How to fix Wine MCF42.DLL error on Lucid?

Tags: 10.04, wine

I'm trying to run Visual Boy Advance and when I use the command

```
wine VisualBoyAdvance
```

I get the following error:

```
err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\zack\\Desktop\\VBA\\VisualBoyAdvance.exe") not found 
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\home\\zack\\Desktop\\VBA\\VisualBoyAdvance.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

and I don't have a clue on how to fix this.

Comment: That means you need to install `mfc42.dll` with Winetricks. Please take a look at the answers in this question: [winetricks can't install mfc42](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169218/winetricks-cant-install-mfc42).

Answer (score 1):

While you can install the missing dll using `winetricks` and use the windows version of Visual Boy Advance, there is in fact a native linux version in Ubuntus repositories, which I recommend to use instead of the exe file.

To install it, open the terminal application and enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install visualboyadvance visualboyadvance-gtk
```

It should be listen in the applications menu after that.