# Running GameRanger on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wine

I have wine installed, and I'm trying to run GameRangerSetup.exe with wine, but it shows the following message on the terminal:

```
err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\akash\\Downloads\\Utilities\\GameRanger\\GameRangerSetup.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\home\\akash\\Downloads\\Utilities\\GameRanger\\GameRangerSetup.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

I do not know how to interpret the message. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have mfc42.dll installed. You can obtain it by opening a terminal and typing:

```
winetricks mfc42
```

It will download the required file and then you probably will be able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

***Problem: MFC42.DLL is missing***

Simple fix and this works for *any* missing .dll files on PlayOnLinux or even Windows itself.

1. Close your PlayOnLinux & Wine programs. Kill all instances. ("ps aux" and "kill -9" commands)
2. Google for the dll file name (*MFC42.DLL*). You'll find a bunch of sites where you can download the file.
3. Drop the file into your Windows virtual drive's System32 folder - *System32* is the core Windows system libraries folder which is scanned and all DLLs there are loaded into Windows:

`/home/user/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/virtual drive name/drive_c/windows/system32`

4. Start your wine/PlayOnLinux and try opening the software again. It should load now.
5. You may have other DLLs etc missing, so repeat the above steps until you have all the necessary DLLs loaded.

Source: Many years of tears of rage, pain and suffering with Windows.

HTH.