# how to install freegate in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have issue installing `tor` so I would like to try use `Freegate` on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Is it possible to run `Freegate` on Linux ?

Comment: What *doesn't work*?

Comment: if you want help with tor ask for it in a separate question ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use tor

check this :http://alternativeto.net/software/freegate/?platform=linux

the installation

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

open the tor browser look for app named : tor-browser

then update the browser by 
clicking on help => about firefox => check for updates

Answer (score 1):

Download FreeGate from here :

> http://dongtaiwang.com/loc/download.en.php

FreeGate is much faster and better, and you can't rely on tor anymore,
so first,
install PlayOnLinux from software-center
and then run these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that you double-click on the FreeGate and if you encountered this Error(mfc42.dll) ,Do this command:

```
winetricks  mfc42
```

and if a window came up click on Ja, to install (I don't know what language is that)click on it.(if it wasn't english though :)

after you run the program, it automatically brings up the internet explorer from windows, Close it. and if you want to use it on the Firefox or chrome in ubuntu you gotta setup a proxy for it and to do so:

Firefox :

openmenu in the right, preferences, choose the Advanced tab and from that choose the Network tab, from connection choose settings,
set the Manual proxy configuration:

HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1 port: 8580 ,(ports always shows up when you start FreeGate)
  check the option, use this proxy server for all protocols and in the end click ok.

Chrome:

and if you want to use it in chrome Do This: in the Terminal, run this command,

```
google-chrome --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8580
```

good luck,

source : 
https://askubuntu.com/a/185555

Answer (score 0):

Not your freegate , that is for windows

You stand alone run TOR. wich will also run firefox.

```
cd /tmp
wget https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/3.6.2/tor-browser-linuxXX-3.6.2_en-US.tar.xz
tar xf tor-browser-linuxXX-3.6.2_en-US.tar.xz
cd tor-browser_en-US/ 
./start-tor-browser
```

where **XX**= 64/32 (your platform)